# Derive a closed-form expression of this recursive formula

Tags: computability-theory, markov-chains, closed-form-expressions

$$\begin{equation}
S(r,k) = f(r)S(0,k-1) + g(r)S(r+1,k-1)
\end{equation}\ ,$$
where $r=0,1,2,\dots$ and $k=1,2,3,\dots$ . Also, $0<f(r)<1$ is an increasing function and $0<g(r)<1$ is a decreasing function, while $f(r)+g(r)<1$.

The base case is $S(r,1) = f(r) + g(r)\ \forall\ r$.

Do you think a closed-form expression of $S(r,k)$ is achievable?

Comment: The conditions on $f$ and $g$ seem irrelevant.

Comment: Possibly. But I think they imply that S(r,k) is bounded.

Comment: You could try the approach with power series from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065067/solving-two-dimensional-recurrence-relation-a-i-j-a-i-j-1-a-i/2065193#2065193

Comment: Just trying it a bit, in order to solve it that way, I needed extra information such as the boundary data $S_{0,k}$ and some relation between $g(r)$ and $g(r+1)$. The boundary data can in principle be determined from the recursion but is tricky. Unless we at least have a known compatible boundary data $S_{0,k}$ , this problem is likely a regular numerical discrete-pde problem with no closed forms. But perhaps there is some other approach or pattern I missed.

Comment: @ThomasKojar If we assume that $S_{0,k}$ is just a variable, could you at least get an analytic expression involving $S_{0,k}$, $f(r)$ and $g(r)$?

Comment: I guess. You can try that approach with the power series and see. They just shift indices around and then Taylor expand.